# How to get tumblr user name from access token

Tags: iphone, tumblr

How can I retrieve tumblr user name from tumblr access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the API documentation thoroughly. You need to call the User Info method through OAuth with the access token and that will return a json object that includes the information that you're wanting and then some.